# Text outside div using @Html.Raw

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Having some issues with a specific div on my mvc website. The problem is that the text is displayed outside of the container

I'm trying to display some content using @Html.Raw because i use the CKEditor to type the content

```
.JobOfferContent {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;

}
<div class="JobOfferContent">@Html.Raw(Model.Content)</div>
```

I have used the word-wrap: break-word. It fixes the problem but it also splits the words in half, which just makes the content hard to read.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what's inside `Model.Content`? just a plain ol' string with no markup?

Comment: The CKEdtior saves the content with markup. <p> <br/> and so on. Why i use the @Html.Raw

Comment: If i remove the @Html.Raw and just add dummy text. The content is displayed accordingly to the CSS class.

Comment: So what styling rules are applied for `p` elements? could this be the problem?

Comment: Didn't think of that... Let me give it a go

Comment: .JobOfferContent p{
 padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

Just displays the same issue as before

Comment: the default margin for `p` elements is usually something like `16px 0px;` or `1em 0`.
try replacing it like so : `.JobOfferContent p{ margin:0; padding:0; }`

Comment: (note that there is no way for me to tell whether that looks good :p, but it will help you pin down the problem)

Comment: Thank you... I can prob work with this..